# difficult time inserting data with textfield( jdbc swing)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing, jdbc

My `insert` into is giving me issues.

Im pretty sure the `Jtextfield` is the problem.

If anyone can give me a nudge in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "oracle");

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String query1 = "INSERT INTO WIN(NAME) VALUES('"+nameTextField.getSelectedText()+"')";


      Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
      stm.execute(query1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added Succesfully.", "Record Added",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: `setAutoCommit` is false, so make sure you `commit` manually.

Comment: You should not concatenate values into a query, use a prepared statement with parameters. That protects you against SQL injection and other nasty problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
nameTextField.getSelectedText()
```

I'm guessing that should be

```
nameTextField.getText()
```

Also, use a `PreparedStatement` for the SQL. You will less likely to make SQL syntax errors. Check out: [geting data from multiple table when selecting a row then clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713360/geting-data-from-multiple-table-when-selecting-a-row-then-clicking-a-button/15713391#15713391) for a basic example.

> Im pretty sure the Jtextfield is the problem.

Well, learn how to do some basic debugging instead of guessing.

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO WIN(NAME) VALUES('"+nameTextField.getSelectedText()+"')";
```

The above code can be written like:

```
String name = textField.getSelectedText();
// now you can verify the value of the name
System.out.println(name);

String query1 = "INSERT INTO WIN(NAME) VALUES('"+ name +"')";
// verify SQL syntax
System.out.println( query1);
```

Of course my first suggestion to use the PreparedStatement is easier, but learn how to display the value of variables when you do debugging.

Comment: @Patrick, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.